# Conda create environment fails with Error: No packages found

Tags: python, conda

This is on Windows (32bit) and the full error message is: `Error: No packages found in current win-32 channels matching: package_name`  I have been unable to get the conda package management to work.
Reinstalling Anaconda didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I had created a file in my home directory .condarc which had the following contents:

```
create_default_packages:
  - PACKAGE_NAME
```

I don't know how I did it.  I think I had followed half asleep an instruction to create the non existent package `package_name`.  Deleting this file then removed the block from creating new conda environments.